# Java reading the contents of an URI

Tags: java, url, uri, bufferedreader

I have a URI which opens a URL in an application (Steam).

```
String uriString = "steam://openurl/https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198118053054/gcpd/730";
URI uri = new URI(uriString);
```

With this URI personal data of different games can be displayed in Steam when logged in. If you are not logged in you will be redirected to the profile.

now i would like to read the content directly from the Steam browser since every user is logged in there by default. Otherwise the users would have to log in to their own internet browser before they start the application.

in the Steam browser you can already save the source of the page with right click then there should be a way to automate this.

so how can I read the content of this URI in the Steam Browser?

Comment: the first part of the url (`steam://...`) declares the protocol. In this case, it leads to the page being opened in the steam brower itself, so this will do us no good. Furthermore, the profile-id (and thus the account) is part of the url (`.../profiles/**76561198118053054**/...`), so this would have to change from user to user. I would recommend taking a look at [Steam's API documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide an implementation of [URLStreamHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) that can handle steam://... urls (or the steam protocol), you should actually expect to catch [MalformedURLExceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/MalformedURLException.html).